# Codeigniter : Check if file_exist in Cpanel

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

[image]

I want check if my images is exist in folder **public_html/monitoring/images/user/$fileimage** , after that i want deleted it and upload new one.

I have model to check if my image exist in that folder with this code :

> My Images is **74139316_9273.jpg**

## Model

```
public function check_image_exist($username)
    {
        $this->db->select('fotoUser');
        $this->db->from('app_user');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $selectOldImage = $this->db->get()->row()->fotoUser;
        if (file_exists('../monitoring/images/user/images/' . $selectOldImage)) {
            unlink('./images/' . $selectOldImage);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this my controller to upload new image and update it.

## Controller

```
 public function updateImageProfilInfo_post()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        $config['upload_path'] = '../monitoring/images/user/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000'; // max size in KB
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE; // For Replace Image name

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $check_image_exist = $this->user_model->check_image_exist($username);
        if ($check_image_exist) {
            // print_r($check_image_exist);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                $errorArray = strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->response(
                    ["status" => "error", "message" => "Failed To Upload Image $errorArray"],
                    REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
                );
            } else {
                $info = $this->upload->data();
                $image_path = $info['raw_name'] . $info['file_ext'];
                $updateImageProfilInfo = $this->user_model->update_image_profil_info_user($username, $image_path);
                if ($updateImageProfilInfo) {
                    $this->response(
                        ["status" => "ok", "message" => "Success Update Image $username"],
                        REST_Controller::HTTP_OK
                    );
                } else {
                    $this->response(
                        ["status" => "error", "message" => "Failed To Update $username Image Profil , Try Again Later ..."],
                        REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->response(
                ["status" => "error", "message" => "Failed To Find Image with Username $username. Try Again Later ..."],
                REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND
            );
        }
```

[image]

But the problem is my image is always not found,  although I'm sure the directory is correct. How can i fixed it ?

Thanks

Comment: Unlink doesn’t have correct path `unlink('./images/' . $selectOldImage); ` second I don’t see an image folder in your folder structer `../monitoring/images/user/images/` should be `../monitoring/images/user/`

Comment: I meant no images folder in your user folder which you are trying to upload file into it. So your path is not correct. Will work fine if you correct path to file

Comment: This sounds embarrassing, I have typo  in `if (file_exists('../monitoring/images/user/images/' . $selectOldImage))` i have double **images**.

Comment: Lol. No worry! you won’t have a guess what mistakes we do sometimes :) Your upload path is not correct too.